# How to create a form in pebble watch

Tags: c, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I am creating a pebble watch app and I would like to create a form where the user could give input for certain parameters.

Something like [this](https://developer.pebble.com/guides/design-and-interaction/recommended/#get-user-input-with-a-form) would serve me well enough, but I cannot find a way to create it in the documentation (maybe I don't know where and how to find it).

Can anyone provide me a better way to accomplish user input feature or is anyone knowing about this topic?

p.s. I would like the user to give 2-3 integers that will be used later in the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll down in the page you linked to, you will see that they link to [example source-code](https://developer.pebble.com/guides/design-and-interaction/implementation/).  Under **Pattern**, click on the one that interests you to see the code.

Getting code to run on the Pebble watch is not necessarily easy.  I am not sure how much you've played around with it, but I would go through the standard **Hello, World** type tutorials before tackling more complex user interactions.  Once you get familiar, you can download the source code to all of the Pebble UI patterns [here](https://github.com/pebble-examples/ui-patterns/).

You will also need to store the information.  This is more complex than you might assume.  You tagged your question to the `C` language, so [here](https://developer.pebble.com/docs/c/) is the Pebble `C` documentation.  [Here](https://developer.pebble.com/docs/c/Foundation/Storage/) are the `C` docs for storage.  It looks like the function you'll want is:

```
status_t persist_write_int(const uint32_t key, const int32_t value)
```

Good luck!